# How does Google analytics measures page load time for virtual pages sent?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have bad performance results in Site Speed Page Timings in Google analytics, for virtualPage, but I can't find way, how does this time is measured (e. g. I do not see parameter in dataLayer object, responsible for timing, or parameter in collect request sent). Moreover I do not have such bad perfomance in action itself.

For example I send {"virtualPage":"newsletter/confirm"}, when check radio-button newsletter, and this action can't take 43 seconds.

If you have any idea, how to debug, please suggest.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the steps in this tutorial and measure Adjusted Bounce Rate instead of regular bounce rate:

http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2322974/how-to-implement-adjusted-bounce-rate-abr-via-google-tag-manager-tutorial

The idea is to implement a timing trigger for visitors (e.g. visitors who stay more than 30 seconds are no longer counted as a bounce and event listeners for clicks within the page)

Comment: You're welcome @DamirGadiev . If you're happy with the answer, you can mark it as a solution for your question, and an upvote would be greatly appreciated too :)